# analysis of RC circuit using Matlab

Tags: circuit-analysis, matlab

I designed the circuit and obtained the desired outputs correctly.
for for circuit it R = 1e3 , C= 0.15e-6, and f = 250 , ( for RC circuit) and in the second part it asks to increase the frequency to 2Kh that is R = 1e3 , C= 0.15e-6, and f = 2kh.
now it asks
Compare the gains and phases from question 1)d) and 1)e). Justify and explain
similarities and/or differences
I know the gain is Vout/Vin but the output looks pretty weird I have an idea but is there a difference between the two? I mean changing the frequency should change the gain or not? 
[image]

here is output/input waveform for circuit with f=250H
[image]

and here is the one with f=2KH
[image]

I also plotted the bode diagram for both circuits. f=250, and f=2kh respectively.
[image]

[image]

here is the code for Bode digram ( frequency domain) 
[image]

Comment: That looks as expected (note the X-axis is log if that is part of your confusion). Why do you think it is odd?

Comment: the question is compare the gain and phase change for both of them. so my question is what is the gain? and why they are the same ?

Comment: @user65652 Gain is not the same. From the time-based plots, the first (at \$f = 250\$) has unity gain (the amplitudes of the purple and yellow plots are the same). But the second (at \$f = 2000\$) has the purple output at much lower amplitude than the yellow input.

Comment: Check the units on your bode plot... rad/s rather than cycles/ sec.

Comment: @ Null , I noticed that too then why the bode diagrams are the same then?

Comment: does that mean the phase change is same for both , right?

Comment: yes it does as there is no difference between the two bode plots. See my updated response as it is a slight tweak on the bode command to help show this.

Comment: By the way the title say RLC but all presented information is for RC

Comment: Yeah, I know, that would be second part of lab. is there a code to plot the phase change as well? it seems it is not clear to with the one they provided

Comment: Thats the point of the bode plot. You can read off the gain & phase change at any frequency. I suspect that is what is being asked so you can see you do not need to depend on the time domain

Comment: the bode plot i obtained for both frequencies are almost  same. it is not clear any changes in phase or gain !.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of a bodeplot. For starters you can't really run a bode plot at different frequencies (just over a tighter range). Only one bode plot run is needed (as I explained) you then read off the frequencies of interest: 250Hz -> read off gain and phase,  2000Hz --> read off gain and phase NOTE the frequency (x-axis) is not only in log but in rad/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two sets of waveforms

1) time domain

2) frequency domain

While you will see a difference between the two time domain plots (higher frequency resulting in a lower output, as expected) you will not between the two frequency domain plots

Why?  it is how the matlab command works. You are not instructing Matlab to provide gain:phase at a particular frequency for the two frequency domain plots, you have essentially instructed Matlab to run a frequency sweep and resultant bode plot twice.

As a result you will not see any difference between these two plots.

--edit--
Based upon the presented matlab code:

The simplest solution to demonstrate a difference at different frequencies is to change the bode function call from

**bode(monSysteme)**

to

**bode(monSysteme,{249,251})**

and also:

**bode(monSysteme,{1999,2001})**

ie a specific frequency range, tight to the freq of interest.

[image]
[image]

PLEASE note, this isn't really needed as you can just read off of the original bode plot the magnitude at 250Hz and 2kHz and see a difference.

If a specific time domain reference point is needed & the desire isn't to read the result off of a bode plot then the **BODE** command isn't the correct command but **lsim** with a specific stim:

```
R=1e3;
C=0.15e-6;
num=1;
denum = [R*C 1];
m = tf(num,denum);

[u,t] = gensig('sin',1/250);
lsim(m,u,t)
figure
[u,t] = gensig('sin',1/2000);
lsim(m,u,t)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh I see, I had an argument with my partner saying that. there must be a gain difference between the two circuits. he said frequency does not change the gain !!

Comment: could you edit the original post and post the script, with the carriage return delimiters

Comment: I added the bode diagram code in the original question

Comment: well I think I asked if I could find the gain through bode diagram. ( time domain) but the graphs are still in frequency domain

Comment: so are you saying the phase changes as frequency changes?

Comment: yes, as shown in the bode plot. It is a 1st order system. G = 1/sqrt(1 + (wRC)^2)  & Phase = arctan(-wRC)   Increase frequency of the input voltage and the output voltage amplitude decreases and the phase increases

Comment: you rock. Thanks a lot. I don't know why they provided a Matlab command to throw off everyone